# Who am I with the death number 5.8

Tags: riddle

> My death number is 5.8
>   Last two days i didn't slept
>   Being compared to an illuminating object in the bad conditions
>   I didn't listen to the person who is everyone's well wisher
>   The hint is that my image is poor
>   My name that you know is not what is my
>   Do you know who am i?

Sorry for not rhyming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Marilyn Monroe
>  Death number 5.8 - Died August 5th, 1962
>  Last two days hadn't slept - possible reference to her death by overdose on sleeping pills
>  Being compared... - refers to Candle in the Wind, by Elton John
>  Didn;t listen - didn't listen to her doctor for not taking drugs
>  The hint is that my image is poor - she had been struggling with depression and poor self-image
>  My name that you know is not what is my - Her real name was Norma Jean Mortenson

Comment: correct...and about the fourth line...she was obsessed with drugs i.e. she didn't listen to her doctor and a doctor is everyone's well wisher...(however if the doctor is selfish then he would pray for everyone's bad health. :p)

Answer (score 5):

Are you ...

> Macbeth?

Here is what I have got so far:

My death number is 5.8

> He dies in [Act 5, Scene 8](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/macbeth/page_216.html).

Last two days i didn't slept

Being compared to an illuminating object in the bad conditions

I didn't listen to everyone's well wisher

The hint is that my image is poor

> He becomes a tyrannical ruler.

My name that you know is not what is my

> Macbeth means "son of life", he seems to be quite the opposite.

Do you know who am i?

Comment: sorry...it is not the correct answer... :( ...let me make a very small edit in my question. It doesn't changes anything but makes the riddle more clear